# Android start service of an app from another android app

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have two applications installed on the device: from one app I want to start a service as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app.service",    "com.app.service.NotificationService"));
  context.startService(i);
```

The second app is only installed but not started.

What I want is to start the notification service(which should create a notification) from the second service by using the above code.

In the manifest file of the second app I declare the service as follows:

```
<service
        android:name=".service.NotificationService"
        android:exported="true" />
```

The problem is that the Notification Service from the second app does not start.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: your question is not clear. You want to start a service inside one application from another application?

Comment: I want to start a service that resides in the second app from my first app by using the above mentioned code. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a great solution but I have fixed my problem by removing the NotificationService file from the com.app.service directory, and adding it to the com.app directory. 
This fixed the issue for me, meaning that I managed to start the service of the second application from the first application.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the second app is the Notifications one right?

If so, what I would try is loading both apps individually first, and then creating a method in your second one to access the information from the first one.

I had a similar scenario, let me just find the solution (somewhere on my laptop) and get back to you more specifically.

Comment: Yes, the second app has a service that creates a notification. And that service I want to start from my first app.

Comment: One more thing, do you want to launch the whole application or just the activity?

Comment: Well, after the notification is created by the service of the second app, I want to start the second app by pressing on the notification from the notification bar.

Comment: Alright, until I figure out how to apply this to your code, I would suggest to look at this: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

It helped solve my problems before.