# Android: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.app.service/.NotificationService } U=0: not found

Tags: android, android-service

This question is related to the following:
[Android start service of an app from another android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605866/android-start-service-of-an-app-from-another-android-app)

What I am trying to do is:

- I have two applications(both are installed but the second one is not started)
- I start the first app and with it I start a service of the second app

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app.service",    "com.app.service.NotificationService"));
  context.startService(i);
  ```
- The service from the second app should display a notification in the notification bar

The service is declared in the manifest file of the second app within the application tags:

```
<service android:name="com.app.service.NotificationService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">

        </service>
```

The service does not start an I get the following message:

```
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.app.service/.NotificationService } U=0: not found
```

Do you have any suggestions on why this issue occurs?

Comment: Can you share more details about your logcat output ?

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any more details regarding this issue in the logcat.

Comment: Try this :  

   startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));

Comment: This won't work because the NotificationService class is located in the second app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a great solution but I have fixed my problem by removing the NotificationService file from the com.app.service directory, and adding it to the com.app directory. 
This fixed the issue for me, meaning that I managed to start the service of the second application from the first application.